# Is it bad when dvdisaster says that some sectors of a dvd disc are unreadable?

Tags: cd-command, dvd

I wanted to check if an image was successfully written to a DVD, so I checked the checksums:

```
$ sha256sum debian-7.3.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
da0249fd52abc0afd4256c754849543f1621255715e57d2265bad97836dc9131  debian-7.3.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso

$ ls -al debian-7.3.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
-rw-r--r-- 1 morfik morfik 3942645760 Dec 25 22:40 debian-7.3.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso

$ dd if=/dev/sr0 bs=2048 count=1925120 | sha256sum
da0249fd52abc0afd4256c754849543f1621255715e57d2265bad97836dc9131  -
1925120+0 records in
1925120+0 records out
3942645760 bytes (3.9 GB) copied, 355.885 s, 11.1 MB/s
```

It looks OK, but the application [dvdisaster](http://dvdisaster.net/en/index.html) has some problems with it and says that some sectors are unreadable:

[image: dvdisaster]

Is it because of my DVD drive or is something wrong with the DVD disc? Should I be worried about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking for an answer for a wile, and when I checked the same CD/DVD several times, the red dots are in different places. So, I looked in `dvdisaster` options and there was something like `skip some sectors after read error`. The default value was 16, and after an error shoved up, I stopped the scanning. In the place of 640 unreadable sectors, I got 16. So, I changed it to 0 in the options, and everything is green now.

I think the read errors are common and the device can read one single sector multiple times before it gives an error that it can't read the CD at all. So, single red spots are harmless, but if there were many of them in one place, that would cause data loss.

Comment: ... That's a lot of false positives that software puts out. Not encouraging.